# how to plot the logistic function for a logreg model with multiple independent variables?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, regression

Say I have a data set with 3 continuous independent variables (iv1, iv2 and iv3) and response variable (r1) for a 0 or 1 classification problem.

Here's how I fit the model using sklearn LogisticRegression() for a case with just one independent variable:

```
# initialize classifier
clf = LogisticRegression()
# feature/target selection
X = df[iv1].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
y = df[r1]
#
sclr = StandardScaler()
X_train = sclr.fit_transform(X)
#
clf.fit(X_train, y)
```

Once I have the model, I am able to plot the logistic function as follows:

```
#
xp = np.linspace(df[iv1].min(),df[iv1].max(),100).reshape(-1,1)
xp_n = sclr.transform(xp)
yp = clf.predict_proba(xp_n)[::,1]
#
```

now I can plot the logistic function using:

```
plt.plot(xp,yp)
```

Now if I fit my model w/ all three independent variables:

```
X = df[[iv1,iv2,iv3]]
y = df[r1]
#
sclr = StandardScaler()
X_train = sclr.fit_transform(X)
#
clf.fit(X_train, y)
```

How do I plot the logistic function (of probabilities) for the combined feature model?
The x-axis here I assume would be: `intercept + iv1*coeff1 + iv2*coeff2 + iv3*coeff3`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is our inability to visualize 4-dimensional data. That is, requiring axes for `iv1`, `iv2` and `iv3`, we need a fourth axis to display the predicted probability. There are several options:

1. You indeed plot `intercept + iv1\*coeff1 + iv2\*coeff2 + iv3\*coeff3`. This effectively makes the plot 2D (and thus easy to plot) but it also somewhat hides the fact that there are three features.
2. Alternatively, you could try to fix one of the features at a representative value and make a 3D plot. This gives already somewhat more info on how the predicted probability vary for different choices of `iv1`, `iv2`, and `iv3`. This is perhaps a particularly nice solution if one of your features only takes a few outcomes. Say a binary variable, or a variable with a limited number of levels, a variable with little spread around its mean, or...
3. Or fix the value of two features and only vary the third, this would again result in a 2D plot.
4. And many more possibilities because you could make a plot for any given line/plane in the (`iv1`,`iv2`,`iv3`)-space...

Note that suggestions 2, 3, and 4 do require you to make predictions not just on the data but also for values on a grid. Overall, the "best" choice probably depends on the particular behaviour/characteristic of your data you would wish to highlight through the plot.

Comment: ahh, got it! I agree, option 1 is easy to look at, but coveys very little info about the individual features/interactions. I had not realized I could simply freeze one of the variables and plot the effects of the other two vs the response. This is very helpful, Thanks!

Comment: It's a pleasure to be helpful... Also, if you are interested in making plots conveying the features/interactions, then you can plot the partial effects.